# How to store URLs in MongoDB using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am building a project where I have to store the URLs in a database. Is there any way to escape URLs? How to store and retrieve it efficiently using Javascript?

Edit: I want a mechanism to convert the url and escape it kind of operation.

Comment: Same way you'd store any other string.

Comment: What should be escaped?

Comment: Store it as String

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood but if you need to retricve the url from the browser it would look some thing like this:
`const currentUrl = window.location.href;`

now if you would like to store this data in a mongoDB collection i would recommend using mongoose https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I dont have any problem in retrieving the url to the API and creating a model schema doc everything. I want a mechanism to convert it into a general form and after retrieval also I have to convert that to the previous form.